# program where user output anser will be print in vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a user input where my output will be coming in vowels.

The result would be:

```
Enter a sentence: my name is Mike
do you want to input more:yes
Enter a sentence: i am from China
Do you want to input more:no
[a,e,i,i,e,i,a,o,i,a]
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? What part of your task are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Question not clear,please clearly specify what is your Input and what you want from that input.

Comment: @vinodsesetti It looks like the output is just listing all the vowels sequentially from the combined input.

Comment: Just simply traverse over the sting and determine alphabet at each position. If a vowel is encountered, add it to the list. In the end just print the list.

Comment: @call me programmer, did any of the answers posted below help solve your problem? If so, you may mark the one that you wish to, thank you!

Comment: yes issue solved

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the user-input should only be `yes/no` or `YES/NO`, I also added a few methods for use input and validating it.

```
def validate_input(inp2):
    if inp2 == 'yes' or inp2 == 'YES' or inp2 == 'no' or inp2 == 'NO':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def take_input(self):
    print("Enter a sentence: ")
    inp = input()
    self.vowels.extend([i for i in inp.lower() if i in 'aeiou'])


class PrintVowels():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vowels = []

    def get_vowels(self):
        take_input(self)

        while True:
            print("Do you want to input more?")
            inp2 = input()
            valid_inp = validate_input(inp2)
            if valid_inp:
                if inp2.lower() == 'no':
                    break
                else:
                    take_input(self)
            else:
                print("Error: Please try again with a valid input!")
                continue

        return self.vowels

ob1 = PrintVowels()
print (ob1.get_vowels())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a sentence: 
my name is Mike
Do you want to input more?
blahhhhWHAAT
Error: Please try again with a valid input!
Do you want to input more?
oops
Error: Please try again with a valid input!
Do you want to input more?
yes
Enter a sentence: 
I am from China
Do you want to input more?
Huhhhh
Error: Please try again with a valid input!
Do you want to input more?
NO
['a', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'e', 'i', 'a', 'o', 'i', 'a']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class PrintVowels():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vowels = []

    def get_vowels(self):
        while True:
            print("Enter a sentence: ")
            inp = input()
            self.vowels.extend([i for i in inp.lower() if i in 'aeiou'])
            print("Do you want to input more?")
            inp2 = input()
            if inp2.lower() == 'no':
                break
        return self.vowels

ob1 = PrintVowels()
print (ob1.get_vowels())

#output['e', 'o', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'o']
```